# How to replace dollar signs before a variable in a string with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, lua

I am having problem replacing:

```
"count: $OFF_COUNT times"
```

with:

```
"count: " .. OFF_COUNT .. " times"
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/\$\([A-Z0-9_]+\)\b/" .. \1 .. "/g'
```

But, it had no effect.

Just an unchanged output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly had the correct command. The only problem is that in basic `sed` syntax the `+` is a literal (equivalent to `[+]`). Quote from `sed`'s [Appendix A Extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html):

> The only difference between basic and extended regular expressions is
>   in the behavior of a few characters: `?`, `+`, parentheses, and braces
>   (`{}`).
>   [...]
>   `c\+`
>       becomes `c+` when using extended regular expressions. It matches one or more ‘c’s.

To enable the usual meaning of `+` write `\+`

```
sed 's/\$\([A-Z0-9_]\+\)\b/" .. \1 .. "/g'
```

or use extended `sed` syntax

```
sed -E 's/\$([A-Z0-9_]+)\b/" .. \1 .. "/g'
```